# Moduli space M(0,H,1)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a K3 surface with $Pic(X) = \mathbf{Z}H$ and $H^2 > 0$. Let $ M = M_X(0,H,1)$ be the moduli space of sheaves on $X$ with Mukai vector $v = (0,H,1)$. Then how can we see that $M$ is smooth? I would like to see an argument showing that $ob(E) \in Ext^2(E,E)$ is zero.

The problem is that trace map $tr : Ext^2(E,E) \to k$ is zero. But I don't know how to show this. I think it should follow from the fact that $tr : End(E) \to O_X$ is zero?